# Resize Arch root partition in gparted

Tags: linux, partition, gparted

my arch linux(antergos) partition is getting small and I wanted to resize it by using a USB stick with the live version of antergos.

So I booted, installed gparted but I'm unable to resize it whysoever.

Can someone tell me why?

Gparted

[image]

When resizing [image: http://imgur.com/ASRXHVU]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot resize the partition because the free space is not adjacent to it. You would have to move /dev/sdb7 to the end of the disk first (it may take very long) and then you can resize /dev/sdb9.